# Using Visual Studio build getting error "MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "Build"."

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

We are trying get Team Foundation Server 2017 to automate a build, and thus far we have always just used Visual Studio to build and publish, but now having Team Foundation Server do it we are running into an issue with circular dependencies.

We are using the Visual Studio build step.

There are multiple projects in the solution (.sln).

The project blows up on references to two other projects which do not reference this project directly or indirectly.

I've looked all over for an article describing how to track down this circular reference, but everything I have found so far talks about MSBuild or it's having an issue with target "Publish" or something other than "Build".

Error:

> ### [error]D:\VS2017\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1279,11):
>
> Error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency
>   graph involving target "Build".
>
> Project "D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\SLNNAME.sln" (1) is
>   building
>   "D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\Inventory\Inventory.csproj" (17)
>   on node 1 (default targets).
>
> D:\VS2017\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1279,11):
>   error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency
>   graph involving target "Build".
>
> [D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\Inventory\Inventory.csproj]
>
> Done Building Project
>   "D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\Inventory\Inventory.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Done Building Project "D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\SLNNAME.sln"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

Here are my build targets in the .sln file:

```
<Target Name="OverrideAppConfigWithTargetPath">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(TransformedConfig)" Condition="'$(TransformedConfig)'!=''">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyTransformedConfig" Condition="'$(TargetName)' != ''">
    <Copy Condition="Exists('$(TransformedConfig)')" SourceFiles="$(TransformedConfig)" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).config" />
    <Copy Condition="Exists('$(TransformedConfig)') And '$(TargetExt)' == '.exe'" SourceFiles="$(TransformedConfig)" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName).vshost.exe.config" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DeployedConfig>$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).config$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)</DeployedConfig>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Copy Condition="Exists('$(DeployedConfig)')" SourceFiles="$(TransformedConfig)" DestinationFiles="$(DeployedConfig)" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Can this solution be built successfully in your local Visual Studio? Can you share a solution sample to reproduce your issue? Or could you explain this "The project that it blows up on references 2 other projects which do not reference this project directly or indirectly."

Comment: Yeah it builds fine in Visual Studio but not using the TFS Visual Studio Build task.

And what i mean by the above comment is project 1 references project 2 and project 3 but neither of them has added a reference back to project 1.  

I'm not sure how to create the sample you ask for, these are part of a much bigger sln that i wouldnt be able to share...

Comment: Can you share me the .csproj file of the 3 projects for me to check. You could upload them  to [here](https://onedrive.live.com).

Comment: Ok i added a zip w/ those three files as .txt's.  INV_Project is the one i'm having issues getting to build, the other two are the projects it references.  Both of these are referenced by several other projects in the same sln and they all work fine.  I've redacted quite a bit so if there's anything specific you need let me know...    Here's the one-drive share link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj0zHV10Vai5gZQOg0S2ZARa1YGSTg

Comment: Please use MSBuild command to build the solution(D:\Agent\2.112.0_work\2\s\SLNNAME\SLNNAME.sln) on your build agent server, is the error still exists?

Comment: Still got the same error using the MSBuild task.

Comment: I ran in to this issue and it was because we had "Package as nuget" set in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same issue.

This helped me:

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/how-to-fix-msbuild-error-msb4006-38787

I had added a post build to a project with the last checkin, and somehow, project dependencies were added to the .sln, too.

It built fine in VS, but not on TFS build.

I just undid the last changes to the solution (see link, remove the new dependency group).

```
ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
    {9D6D8692-16DD-452C-9D08-1498B3D51A9F} = {9D6D8692-16DD-452C-9D08-1498B3D51A9F}
    {9BE28BBA-B3F6-4076-B989-3B1B48DACF38} = {9BE28BBA-B3F6-4076-B989-3B1B48DACF38}
EndProjectSection
```

Don't know if that fixes your problem, during googling I found many similar issues with rather different causes/solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This error happens when:

1. You run MSBuild on a machine with .NET 4.5 installed
2. You build a project referencing a solution where the SLN file contains dependencies in the SLN.

These dependencies are the dependencies you’ll get if you right-click a project in Solution Explorer, choose Project Dependencies, and start checking projects. This is usually unnecessary as project dependencies can be inferred from the References.
The fix is to open the SLN file in your favorite text editor, and search for sections like this:

Project("{AAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProjectName", "MyProjectName\MyProjectName.csproj", "{B10E1FCF-DFBA-44A8-830F-6F3B54DFA7CB}"

```
ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject

    {B9E9F8CE-A607-4A6C-97F7-2BD439122F89} = {B9E9F8CE-A607-4A6C-97F7-2BD439122F89}

EndProjectSection
```

EndProject

Just delete the entire section, so your Project node looks like this:

Project("{AAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProjectName", "MyProjectName\MyProjectName.csproj", "{B10E1FCF-DFBA-44A8-830F-6F3B54DFA7CB}"

EndProject

Now you should be able to use MSBuild successfully.

Comment: The answer you posted is a direct copy paste from the blog linked by [Andreas Reiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457722/using-visual-studio-build-getting-error-msb4006-there-is-a-circular-dependency/52302812#52302812).